# Internet sharing with iptables: choosing which connection to share

Tags: networking, iptables, connection-sharing

I have a computer with two network devices (`eth0` and `wlan0`), both connected to the internet (two different connections/isp).
I'm trying to share the connection of `wlan0` to another computer connected via ethernet to `eth0`.

What I'm doing is:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

From the client computer I can then connect to this one, but the internet connection that gets shared is the one on `eth0` and not the one on `wlan0`.

If I disable the internet connection on `eth0` (by setting no gateway), then the connection to be shared is the one on `wlan0`. However, I'd like to have both internet connections enabled and specify to iptables which one to share. Is this possible?

What am I missing? Do I need some forwarding rule?

Comment: what is output of `sysctl -a | grep net.ipv4.ip_forward`, is FORWARD Chain is allowed ? could you please add your iptables rules. and what is client side gateway ?

Comment: the output is `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`. Forward chain is allowed and there are no other rules beside the one I posted above. The client side gateway is the local address of the computer that should share the connection. Note that sharing the connection is working, it's just not sharing the one I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem like your default gw is on eth0 and client is redirected to it (via a icmp redirect).

To fix your setup you need to add a routing rule stating that all packets incoming from `client_ip` should be routed to `wlanO_gw`.

Try adding a new routing table:

- Edit `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and add a line for a new table, for example `252 masq` where `252` is the table id and `masq` is the new table name.
- Add a rule to route ip_client packets with table masq

  ip rule add from ip_client/32 table masq
- add a default gw to the masq table

  ip ro add default via wlan0_gw  table masq

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for. This works perfectly if I use the exact commands you posted, however if I try changing the first one to `ip rule add from ip 192.168.0.0/24 table masq` (instead of `192.168.0.3/32`) in order to allow routing of packets from all the addresses of the subnet connected to `eth0`, it stops working. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The rule match your local eth0 ip. Try adding iif eth0, ie `ip rule add from 192.168.0.0/24 iif eth0 table masq`

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick!